# SSIS : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012, bids

I have developed new DTSX package in SSDT and it's executing fine when i run it through the SSDT window.

Same package i am trying to execute from the calling application (.EXE) using below code and it gives

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" error.

Guide me in finding out the root cause and original error message

Then i tried to enable the logging in the DTSX (by enabling all events), still i am getting same error message and it's not pointing exact "task" which is causing the problem. I am unable to find the root cause and the exact error message.

Am i mismacthing any references ? Below is my code

```
Public Sub Execute()     
     Dim app As New Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application
            Dim objPackageResults As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult
        Try 
            objPackage = app.LoadPackage(PackageFile, Nothing)

            InitPackageParams()

            objPackageResults = objPackage.Execute()
        Catch ex As System.IO.IOException
            MsgBox(ex.InnerException)
            blnError = True
        End Try

End Sub     

Private Sub InitPackageParams()

        objPackage.Variables.Item("RegionCode").Value = RegionCode
        objPackage.Variables.Item("UName").Value = _userName
        objPackage.Variables.Item("Password").Value = (SecureStringHelper.GetStringFromSecureString(_password))
        objPackage.Variables.Item("Server").Value = _server
        objPackage.Variables.Item("Catalog").Value = _catalog
        objPackage.Variables.Item("IsTrusted").Value = (CInt(_isTrusted))
        objPackage.Variables.Item("ClearingDate").Value = ClearingDate
        objPackage.Variables.Item("Currency").Value = CurrCode
        objPackage.Variables.Item("Source").Value = Source
        objPackage.Variables.Item("Destination").Value = Destination

End Sub
```

Comment: Which is the line thriwing the error? Plz debug and reply

Comment: Hello Hadi, 
objPackageResults = objPackage.Execute() is causing error.

Comment: what is the target framework for your applicaiton + DTS dll versions